# onClick touch version

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have this code right now that works with mouse, but when I try to use it with my phone, it doesn't work.

```
<div style="background:green;"id="green"class="tools"onClick="color(this)"></div>
<div style="background:blue;"id="blue"class="tools"onClick="color(this)"></div>
<div style="background:red;"id="red"class="tools"onClick="color(this)"></div>
<div style="background:yellow;"id="yellow"class="tools"onClick="color(this)"></div>
<div style="background:orange;"id="orange"class="tools"onClick="color(this)"></div>
<div style="background:black;"id="black"class="tools"onClick="color(this)"></div>
<div id="white"onClick="color(this)"><img src="Eraser.png"></div>
<div id="delete"onClick="erase()"><img src="delete.png"></div>
```

I think phones don't react on onClick. Is there a mobile version for this?

Comment: What's your final goal with this code?

Comment: You could try using button perhaps instead and styling them with css?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using divs with onclick you may consider using a button and add css to it. Then use an onfocus to the button. Onclick isn't reliable on phones and such, but focus is. Here is the code:

```
<input type="button" style="background:green; width:100%;" id="green"class="tools" onfocus="color(this)">
```

Tell me if it doesn't work.

Comment: Good job mentioning phone reliability!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is `ontouchstart` and opposite `ontouchend` properties.

Note: if you want to know coordinates of event, it will be an array of all touches in `event.touches` array.